# How to add +1 to var with href?

Tags: php, html

I have this quantity (var name: $Quantidade) displayed from a cart and need to add + and - hrefs to make it increase/decrease value.

Quantity:
[quantity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov72g.png)

Full table:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1NEO.png)

The quantity var always starts at 1.

All my attempts have failed.

Here is some code for the table (works if the + href is removed):

```
<table class="cart" width=700px cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px;" rules="none" align="center">
    <tr height=40px align="center">
        <td>Product</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Delete</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    // Carrinho
        $total=0;
        foreach($_SESSION['venda'] as $Prod => $Quantidade):
            $SqlCarrinho = mysqli_query($conect,"SELECT * FROM produto WHERE id= '$Prod'");
            $ResAssoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($SqlCarrinho);
            echo '<tr height=40px align="center">';
                echo '<td>'.$ResAssoc['descricao'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.number_format($ResAssoc['preco'],2,",",".").'€</td>';
                echo '<td>-</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$Quantidade.'</td>';
                echo '<td><a href="#?more=true&par='.$Prod.'">+</a></td>';
                echo '<td><a href="index.php?del='.$ResAssoc['id'].'#carrinho" style="text-decoration:none; color:black;">x</a></td>';

                $total += $ResAssoc['preco'] * $Quantidade;
            echo '</tr>';   
        endforeach;

        echo '<tr height=40px>';
            echo '<td colspan="6" align="right">Total: '.number_format($total,2,",",".").'€</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo'</table>';
```

Here is some code for the sessions I use:

```php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['more'])){ $_SESSION['venda'] [$_GET['par']] = $_GET['par'] + 1 ; }

if(isset($_SESSION['venda'])){}
else{ $_SESSION['venda'] = array(); }

if(isset($_GET['par'])){ $_SESSION['venda'] [$_GET['par']] = 1 ; }

if(isset($_GET['del'])){ 
$Del = $_GET['del'];
unset($_SESSION['venda'][$Del]);
```

Everything works until I add the + href, then it disformats the table:
[broken table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBy9x.png)

I have confirmed its not a css error, the href is gone with/without css.

Comment: Add your Table Heading HTML

Comment: @LaljiTadhani done.

Comment: this line: echo '<td><a href="#?more=true&par='.$Prod.'>+</a></td>'; seem mis double quote for href property

Comment: @NguyênNgôDuy sorry I didn't understand what you meant...

Comment: <td><a href="#?more=true&par='.$Prod.'"> change this line, you fotgot `"` double quote for href

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesnt add +1 to the displayed var

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `#` in the link.

`<a href="?more=true&par='.$Prod.'>+</a>`

instead of

`<a href="#?more=true&par='.$Prod.'>+</a>`

When sending requests to your server, the browser ignores everything after the first `#`. Your GET parameters are not sent with the request currently.

---

**Update**

Check out the marked line. It resets venda → par every time par is set (which is always the case if you want to increase your value). Maybe you also want this to initialize the var. In this case you need to fix the if statement (`if(!isset($_GET['par'])){ /* ... */ }`). Venda gets reseted too.

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['more'])){ $_SESSION['venda'] [$_GET['par']] = $_GET['par'] + 1 ; }

if(isset($_SESSION['venda'])){}
else{ $_SESSION['venda'] = array(); }

// This line
if(isset($_GET['par'])){ $_SESSION['venda'] [$_GET['par']] = 1 ; }

if(isset($_GET['del'])){ 
$Del = $_GET['del'];
unset($_SESSION['venda'][$Del]);
```

---

**Update 2**

I think you want the code like this:

```
session_start();

// First, check if all vars are initialized

//  Init if 'venda' is NOT set
if (!isset($_SESSION['venda'])) {
  $_SESSION['venda'] = array();
}

// Init if 'venda['par'] is not set
if (isset($_GET['par']) && !isset($_SESSION['venda'][$_GET['par']])) {
  $_SESSION['venda'][$_GET['par']] = 1;
}

// Run the updates/deletions

// Increase if 'more' is set
if (isset($_POST['more']) && isset($_GET['par'])) {
  $_SESSION['venda'][$_GET['par']] += 1;
}

// Delete
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
  $Del = $_GET['del'];
  unset($_SESSION['venda'][$Del]);
}
```

Comment: still doesn't work, just redirects me to the top of the page

Comment: Okay, i once again updated my answer. Does it work now?

Comment: No, I have a button to add an item to the cart, would that code help?

Comment: What's the issue? Did you try to fix the current errors yourself? With the code you provided until now I think it should work like this.

Comment: the href seems to work since the link text changes, but no numbers change.. here is a gif: https://ibb.co/jzT500v

Comment: Can you echo the value (venda[par]) before and after the if statement which should increase the value?

Comment: Use [var_dump](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to print the session[venda] variable. Like this: `var_dump($_SESSION['venda'])`

Comment: this was the result: array(1) { [31]=> int(1) }

Comment: Before and after the if statement?

Comment: in the sessions? yes

Comment: And if you change `$_SESSION['venda'][$_GET['par']] = 1;` to `$_SESSION['venda'][$_GET['par']] = $_SESSION['venda'][$_GET['par']] + 1`?

Comment: same thing, would you like me to link you a downloadable file of the page?

Comment: This could work. However you need to understand, that I can't invest too much time to fix your script.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/udvdl254vun3722/cart.zip/file I know, thank you for the help. I apreciate it very much

Comment: Hey! I found a way to change the variable!! but the displayed one doesn't update.. how do i make it updade in the table? look -> https://ibb.co/xSZrfdb